# perl encryption script IDEA

Tags: linux, perl, encryption, encryption-symmetric

Hi everyone im making a perl script to encrypt and decrypt text, i just have started i have this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use Crypt::IDEA;

my $key = pack("H32", "0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF");
my $cipher = new IDEA $key;
my $palabra= "plaintex";
my $ciphertext = $cipher->encrypt($palabra);  # NB - 8 bytes

print unpack("H16", $ciphertext), "\n";

my $plaintext = $cipher->decrypt($ciphertext);

print $plaintext , "\n";
```

The trouble is  the text to encrypt must be of 8 bytes of length. why? if i put "plaintext" instead "plaintex" gives me error.

```
input must be 8 bytes long at /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/Crypt/IDEA.pm line 62.
```

Comment: The error states that it must be 8 ***bytes*** not 8 *bits*, as you assert in your question. There's a big difference between the two. Just FYI.

Comment: Please create object in modern way: Crypt::IDEA->new($key);

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wrap **Crypt::IDEA** with **Crypt::CBC** - it will allow to use non-aligned data length. See [doc for Crypt::CBC](http://search.cpan.org/~lds/Crypt-CBC-2.31/CBC.pm).

This is because IDEA and many other crypt algorithms are block encryption algorithms. This means they operate with blocks of data of specified size, so data you encrypting must be prepared (padded with zeros or whatever)

Answer (score 1):

Try  [Crypt::CBCeasy](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Crypt%3a%3aCBCeasy)

```
#!/usr/bin/perl --
use strict; use warnings;
use Crypt::CBCeasy qw/ IDEA /;

my $key     = 'shabba';
my $text    = "plaintex"; ## not a file, not -f -r $text
my $crypted = IDEA::encipher( $key, $text );
my $detext  = IDEA::decipher( $key, $crypted );
print join "\n", $key, $text, unpack( 'H*', $crypted ), $detext, '';

__END__
shabba
plaintex
53616c7465645f5fb5ec01275eb466c4b9b69f3edb7568b42c1713416d33b7aa
plaintex
```